# Can't upgrade Mattermost to Enterprise edition

Tags: mattermost

I'm trying to upgrade (Gitlab) Mattermost to Enterprise edition via the free trial but this message pops up every time I try to do so. Problem is that the command the error is talking about isn't displayed and I have no idea what I should do and on which file. I'm self hosting via Gitlab by the way. Here's the exact error message:

> Mattermost was unable to upgrade to Enterprise Edition. The Mattermost system user mattermost does not have write access to the necessary binary file. A system administrator can update the file permissions by executing the following command on the server where Mattermost is installed:
>
> After changing the file permissions, try to upgrade Mattermost again. When you have upgraded and restarted, remember to restore the original binary file permissions:

[image: Error message]

Thanks!

I tried to search for the mattermost binary but couldn't find it.